# Unable to deploy spring boot jar application

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, executable-jar

I'm developping a spring boot application and it works fine when I run the command:

`mvn spring-boot:run`

But when deploying jar file with the command:

`java -jar target\jarfile.jar`

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hrServicesSilo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hrServicesSilo': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.intranet.si.model.hr.Employee
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a `repository` so I assume you use `spring-data`. It is strange that it works in maven and not working after packaging so you can try the following:

1. Check that you use `spring-maven-plugin` to package your application.
2. Try to add `@EntityScan("com.intranet.si.model.hr")` (can also be `com.intranet.si.model` to recursivly catch all models in the package and sub-packages) to one of your configuration classes or to the application class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`). This will notify spring + hibernate where to scan for entities. Also make sure your entity is annotated with `@Entity`.
3. I guess that you already have `@EnableJpaRespotories` in one of your configuration files but make sure it is configured as well.

Comment: I already added `@EntityScan` but when i add `@EnableJpaRepositories`, it gives me another error: 
`Field employeeRepository in com.intranet.si.services.hr.impl.EmployeeServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.`

Comment: I dont think it's problem of developement because it works with `mvn spring-boot:run`. What does this command do that `java -jar `does not?

Comment: In general if you package your application with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and use the provided JAR it should be the same, `mvn spring-boot:run` use this plugin to start the application and when packages `java -jar` use a runner that the plugin package in your JAR that should run it in the same fashion

Comment: You have `spring-data-jpa` in your pom/gradle? (also make sure it is not in `provided` or something like that). Spring should automatically load everything if you have `@SpringBootApplication` and the only thing i can think about of of my head that can be different when packaged or not is if something is in `optional` / `provided` etc

Comment: No i don't have `spring-data-jpa` nor `optional`or `provided` options in my pom.xml.

Comment: Try to add it to your pom (also post your pom.xml in the question): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: I add it to pom.xml, nothing change